# What is the physical meaning of real part of susceptibility for forced harmonic oscillator with damping?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Many kinds of systems can be modeled as a driven harmonic oscillator with damping. The response of such systems (for example Lorentz model for dielectrics in electromagnetism) is characterized by complex susceptibility $\hat{\chi(\omega)} = \chi^`(\omega) + i \chi^{``}(\omega)$.

The $\chi^{``}(\omega)$ is proportional to the losses in the system or power one has to constantly pump to support the oscillation.

If we look at the graph for both with arbitrary parameters (violet is $\chi^`(\omega)$, black is $\chi^{``}(\omega)$ ):

[image]

For black curve it is intuitively clear - higher amplitude at resonance - more loses - more energy has to be pumped to sustain it.

If we look at the violet curve, it first has a maximum, then 0 at resonance, and then negative.

**What is the physical significance of the real part of susceptibility (similar to 'losses' for imaginary part) and how does it correlates with a shape of frequency dependence? Is there a meaningful physical quantity, that can be attached to it?**

So far my best result was to treat real and imaginary parts as "in-phase" part of response (with respect to driving force) and imaginary as "out-of-phase" part, which also does the work.

**EDIT**: It seems that within the resonance linewidth (in between the peak and the dip), one could say that it is a frequency shift between driving force and natural frequency.
But how to extend it beyond the resonance linewidth?

Or asked differently, what is the reason for a peak?